# RML - adding second page as blank one

Tags: html, report, rml

I have defined specific graphics on rml template like this:

```
<pageTemplate id="first">
    <frame id="first" x1="15.0" y1="42.0" width="539" height="758"/>
    <pageGraphics> 
    ... graphics defined here ...
    </pageGraphics>
```

Then I add in `story` tag this:

```
<story>
    <condPageBreak height="40cm"/> 
</story>
```

Then I get two pages, but second page has same graphics as the first one. But i need second page to be just a blank page, without any graphics. How could I do this?

In short I need template to be two pages - first with graphics defined, the second simple blank page.
The problem is that if I get to more pages, it will simply copy everything (I guess that is standard behavior).

Answer (score 1):

First define number of pageTemplate you want in template tag

```
<template pageSize="(595.0,842.0)" title="Test" allowSplitting="20">
<pageTemplate id="first">
    <frame id="first" x1="15.0" y1="42.0" width="539" height="758"/>
    <pageGraphics> 
    ... graphics defined here ...
    </pageGraphics>
</pageTemplate>
<pageTemplate id="second">
<frame id="second" x1="15.0" y1="42.0" width="539" height="758"/>
<pageGraphics> 
    ... graphics defined here ...
    </pageGraphics>
</pageTemplate>
</template>
```

then in story tag add

```
<setNextTemplate name="second" />
```

and now all the pages will follow second pageTemplate